# Current User filter in a Data Sheet not showing rows until a row header is clicked

Tags: list-view

I have a list that using a Current User Filter.

When the view is opened the list is in Datasheet Mode.  There are no rows displayed until one of the headers are clicked on, then all of the correctly filtered appear.

The field I am filtering on is a  Calculated Field, calculation based on concatenating an two single line text columna.

Why are the rows empty until I click on the header?  How can I resolve this?

Thank you!